# Angular select option value not setting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my array of objects assigned to `$scope.roles`:

```
[{"id":1,"friendly_name":"Super Admin"},{"id":2,"friendly_name":"Admin"},{"id":3,"friendly_name":"User"}];
```

In my HTML I then have the following

`<select ng-model="user.role" ng-options="r.id as r.friendly_name for r in roles"></select></div>`

```
<select ng-model="user.role" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-options="r.id as r.friendly_name for r in roles">
   <option value="0">Super Admin</option>
   <option value="1">Admin</option>
   <option value="2">User</option>
</select>
```

The value is incorrect, as it should be relating to the `id`, rather than just starting from 0. Any clues why?

Comment: No, the value is correct. They use the `index` of the item in the list; `user.role` will contain the `r.id`. The inner workings of `ng-options` is of no concern to you; you should never need to specifically get the `value` of the `<select>`, you just access the `ng-model` which is `user.role`

Comment: Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/). It may help you understand why object binding is important in AngularJS.